# sliding in and out div from right using same image - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need some JQuery help...

I want to slide in a div from the right taking 25% of the screen width.
How can I use the same '#trigger-left a' to slide out the div? (i.e. width: 0px)

JQuery:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#trigger-left a").click(function(){
        var rightCol = $("#right-col");
            rightCol.animate({width:'25%'},350);
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="trigger-left"><a href="#"><img src="images/menu-icon.png" border="0"></a></div>


<div id="right-col">Content right column</div>
```

Looking forward to your solutions!

Comment: Can't use an if in the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(function() {    
   $("#trigger-left a").click(function(){
    var rightCol = $("#right-col");
        if(rightCol.width()==0)
        {
            rightCol.animate({width:'25%'},350);
        }
        else
        {
            rightCol.animate({width:'0%'},350);
        }

    return false;
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just track what state it's in. In this way can keep direction going which may not be possible if clicked in the middle of a transition if using the widths.

```
$(function() { 
    var triggered = false;
    $("#trigger-left a").click(function(){
        var rightCol = $("#right-col");
        if(!triggered){
             rightCol.animate({width:'25%'},350);
             triggered = true;
        } else {
             triggered = false;
             rightCol.animate({width:'0%'},350);
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by clicking the same link the div will slide out.
Here you are:

```
$(function () {
    var div = $("#"right-col");
    $("#trigger-left a").click(function (e) {
        if ($(div).width() != 0) {
            $(div).animate({width:'0px'},350);
        } else {
            $(div).animate({width:'25%'},350);
        }
    });
});
```

Try that if it didn't work I will edit my answer. Good luck ;)

Comment: First answer by durgesh.patle is working for me. Thanks for your input.